# Difference between Tesseract 3 and Tesseract 4?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

What are the major differences between Tesseract 3 and Tesseract 4 ? And why should I choose one over the other ?

Answer (score 8):

Tesseract 4.0's accuracy is better than a tesseract 3. Tesseract 4 uses deep learning model: Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) neural network which is a kind of Recurrent Neural Network (RNN).

But please check system requirements e.g. If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS then Tesseract will be installed with version 3 and not 4. And if you are using Ubuntu 18.04 then you can install latest Tesseract version 4.

For more details please refer the following articles:

1. Here short theory for tesseract is given:
   https://limitlessdatascience.wordpress.com/2019/07/01/tesseract-4-0-intro-installation/
2. Tesseract 3 Vs 4 output comparision: https://limitlessdatascience.wordpress.com/2019/07/31/tesseract-3-0-and-4-0-implementation-and-output-comparison/